# Python datetime timedelta attributes

Tags: design, python

In the python `datetime` module, `timedelta` objects take weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds as arguments upon instantiation. However, after the `timedelta` is created, the only two attributes it has of the former listed are days, seconds, and microseconds.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably to keep the size of the object small.
In the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) is clearly stated that all the arguments are converted into those three units.

Comment: It's weird to me that there aren't `@property` methods that calculate minute, hour, etc. for you on access, but thanks for the help.